# Array of Markers - Passing info held in array to InfoBox

Tags: arrays, api, google-maps, markers, infobox

I have an array of markers which are displaying fine.  The problem I have is displaying an InfoBox for each using content held in the array.  The array is called store_pins, elements 4 and 5 hold the values to be passed to the InfoBox (element 4 contains the filename of an image, 5 the caption for the image).  The InfoBox code will

The InfoBox needs to be called when the Marker is clicked and should go at the bottom of my code where I have the comment // INFO BOX CODE GOES HERE.

My code in full is as follows:

```js
    var map;
    var pop_up_info = "border: 0px solid black; background-color: #ffffff; padding:15px; margin-top: 8px; border-radius:10px; -moz-border-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px; box-shadow: 1px 1px #888;";


    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    
    function initialize() {
        var map_center  = new google.maps.LatLng(55.144178,-2.254122);
        var store_pins  = new Array();
        var pin_marker  = new Array();
        var pin_info    = new Array();
        var pin_infoop  = new Array();
        
        store_pins = [
            ['Bellingham Co-Op', 55.144178, -2.254122,'pin','bellinghamcoop.jpg','Staff at Bellingham Co-Op'],
            ['Leicester Tigers - Kingston Park', 55.018754, -1.672230,'rugby','kingparktigers.jpg','Stu with the Leicester Tigers Rugby Team'],
            ['The Hawick PSA Team', 55.421825, -2.797123,'rugby','hawickpsa.jpg','The Hawick PSA Team']
        ];

    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 3,
        minZoom: 3,
        center: map_center,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("trackingT-map"), myOptions);
    
        // Main Loop
        
        
        for(i=0;i<store_pins.length;i++)
        {
        var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(store_pins[i][1], store_pins[i][2]);
        var pinIcon = {
            url: 'icons/shirtpin.png',
            //The size image file.
            size: new google.maps.Size(50, 55),
            //The point on the image to measure the anchor from. 0, 0 is the top left.
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            //The x y coordinates of the anchor point on the marker. e.g. If your map marker was a drawing pin then the anchor would be the tip of the pin.
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(25, 20)
        };
        var pinShape = {
            coord: [0,0,50,55],
            type: 'rect'
        };

        pin_marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker(
        {
                position:       pos,
                map:            map,
                title:          store_pins[i][0],
                icon:           pinIcon,
                shape:          pinShape,
                zIndex:         107
           } 
        );
            
        pin_infoop[i] = {
                disableAutoPan: false,
                maxWidth: 0,
                pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-241, 0),
                zIndex: null,
                boxStyle: { 
                background: "url('infobox/pop_up_box_top_arrow.png') no-repeat",
                opacity: 1,
                width: "430px"
                },
                closeBoxMargin: "10px 2px 2px 2px",
                closeBoxURL: "icons/button_close.png",
                infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1),
                isHidden: false,
                pane: "floatPane",
                enableEventPropagation: false,
                content:   store_pins[i][5]
        };

        pin_info[i] = new InfoBox(pin_infoop[i]);

            
            
        google.maps.event.addListener(pin_marker[i], 'click', function() {
            map.panTo(this.position);
            map.setZoom(10);
            pin_info[i].open(map, this);
        });
} 
};
```

Comment: There isn't any InfoBox code in your question, what have you tried that you thought should work?

Comment: Sorry, posted the wrong code snippet.  I have edited it above.  pin_infoop[i] is an array containing the infoBox options.  pin_info[i] is an array containing the infoBox's themselves.

I am getting the following error within the addListener event:

Cannot read property 'open' of undefined which occurs at the statement pin_info[i].open(map, this);

So clearly there is an issue passing the InfoBox array into the Listener.

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get a javascript error with your code:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined
```

on this line:

```
pin_info[i].open(map, this);
```

i=3 and the highest available index of pin_info is 2.

Your problem is the common issue of defining infowindows/boxes in a loop.   Solved in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example) with anonymous function closure:

Change this:

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(pin_marker[i], 'click', function() {
        map.panTo(this.position);
        map.setZoom(10);
        pin_info[i].open(map, this);
    });
```

To:

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(pin_marker[i], 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
        map.panTo(this.position);
        map.setZoom(10);
        pin_info[i].open(map, this);
    }
  })(pin_marker[i], i));
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95g4h9f4/2/) (had to change the icons and some of the properties of the infobox so I could see what was going on as your code doesn't work as is)

Comment: I could kiss you, but my wife wouldn't like it! Many thanks, I've been scratching my head over this for ages.

Just one quick question though, where you have:

google.maps.event.addListener(pin_marker[i], 'click', (function(marker, i) {

should it not say (function(pin_marker, i) {

?

Comment: That is the code that is working in the [proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95g4h9f4/2/).  The marker variable isn't actually being used in that code (I copied it from the example, your code uses `this` where `marker` would go), the closure on `i` is what matters.